# How to find if folder name contains spaces in Bash

Tags: bash, find, spaces

I have text file (file.txt) containen folders:

```
/Volumes/my driver/foo/
/Volumes/drive 2/bar/
...
```

Then I want to find like jpg files and open in app. The problem is that find doesn't accept space if are in list even I add quotes to the text file.
like

```
cat file.txt | while read -r line ; do
    result=$(find $line -name '*.jpg')
done
```

Then next problem would be to read result to table and open it in app.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that find doesn't accept space

That's not correct. You just need to make sure to remove unnecessary `cat`, use loop properly and quote variable properly like this:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    result=$(find "$line" -name '*.jpg')
    echo "do something with $result"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: It say "No such file or directory"

Comment: Not clear which line can give that error. Run this script with `bash -x` and check output.

Comment: Sorry, it was my error. I was replaced " " with "\ " in folder names. Now I removed these and it works.